Saving enum string properties into database
I have enum in java
public enum Day {
    MONDAY("D1", "X"),
    TUESDAY("D2", "X"),
    WEDNESDAY("D3", "X"),
    THURSDAY("D4", "X"),
    FRIDAY("D5", "X"),
    SATURDAY("D6", "X"),
    SUNDAY("D7", "Y");

    private final String value;
    private final String value2;

    Day(String value, String value2) {
        this.value = value;
    this.value2 = value2
    }

    public String getvalue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getvalue2() {
        return value2;
    }
}

in my hibernate entity I have
  @Column(name = "day", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Day day; 

on postgres database it saves MONDAY but I want D1.
I tried EnumType.String but I need something else I guess

Does this answer your question? How to get value from a Java enum

no. I have problem with saving on the database.

That's what, you need to get proper value from enum and push it to DB. Whatever you send it will save it there. See duplicate question on how to get value.

You can implement an AttributeConverter class, then annotate your enum with
@Convert(converter = DayConverter.class)

Eg. (the second function needs some more work)
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DayConverter implements AttributeConverter<Day, String> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Day day) {
        return day.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Day convertToEntityAttribute(String databaseValue) {
        return MONDAY;
    }
}


add these following methods to your Enum class.
to get the enum from a value(eg. return MONDAY when you pass D1):
public static Day fromValue(String value) {
    for (Day day : Day.values()) {
        if (day.getValue().equals(value)) {
            return day;
        }
    }
    // throw some exception
    return null; 
}

// input: "D1" -> output : MONDAY

to get value when you pass Day(eg. return D1 when you pass Day.MONDAY):
public static String toValue(Day day) {
    return day.getValue();
}
// input: Day.MONDAY -> output : "D1"

NOTE: but it seems that you are trying to save Enum into your database column, so you should pass a day to your column.
